# Scala Play framework: access messages from QueryStringBindable

Tags: scala, playframework

May I ask your help with Play framework of v2.6.13.
I trying to validate query string parameters and therefore I've implemented following QueryStringBindable:

```
import play.api.data.validation._ 
import play.api.i18n.Messages 
import play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class PagingParams(offset: Int, limit: Int)

object PagingParams {

  val DefaultOffset = 1
  val DefaultLimit = 20   
  val OffsetParamKey = "offset"   
  val LimitParamKey = "limit"   
  val ValidationConstraints = Seq(Constraints.min(1), Constraints.max(100000))

  implicit def queryStringBinder(implicit intBinder: QueryStringBindable[Int]) = new QueryStringBindable[PagingParams] {

    override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, PagingParams]] = {
      val result = for {
        offset <- Try(intBinder.bind(OffsetParamKey, params).get).recover {
          case _ => Right(DefaultOffset)
        }
        limit <- Try(intBinder.bind(LimitParamKey, params).get).recover {
          case _ => Right(DefaultLimit)
        }
      } yield {
        (offset.right.toOption, limit.right.toOption)
      }
      result match {
        case Success((maybeIndex, maybeLimit)) =>
          ParameterValidator(ValidationConstraints, maybeIndex, maybeLimit) match {
            case Valid =>
              Some(Right(PagingParams(maybeLimit.get, maybeLimit.get)))
            case Invalid(errors) =>
              Some(Left(errors.zip(Seq(OffsetParamKey, LimitParamKey)).map {
                case (ValidationError(message, value), param) => Messages(message, param, value)
              }.mkString(", ")))
          }
        case Failure(e) => Some(Left(s"Invalid paging params: ${e.getMessage}"))
      }
    }

    override def unbind(key: String, pagingParams: PagingParams): String =
      intBinder.unbind(OffsetParamKey, pagingParams.offset) + "&" + intBinder.unbind(LimitParamKey, pagingParams.limit)   
  } 
}
```

Problem is that running application I'm getting following error:

> An implicit MessagesProvider instance was not found.

Unfortunately I can't find any help of how can I implicitly inject MessagesProvider so that I can retrieve messages from messages file.

Here is how my endpoint looks like in routes file:

```
GET     /table                      controllers.TableController.index(pagingParams: PagingParams)
```

Thank you very much. Please accept my apologies if similar question has been asked already.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the Play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Passing-MessagesProvider-to-Form-Helpers), your controller class should inject (you could `import com.google.inject.Inject` for injection) `ControllerComponents`, extends `AbstractController` and `I18nSupport`:

```
class MyController  @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)
  extends AbstractController(cc) with play.api.i18n.I18nSupport { 
    ??? //your controller methods
}
```

Also you need to use `requestHeader` and `MessageProvider` instances, within your views file:

```
@(viewsElement: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader, messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it's not quite right. Problem is that code is executed before entering controller, i.e., framework sees PagingParams defined in routes file and tries to find QueryStringBindable which will tell how to map query string arguments '?index=1&limit=10' into PagingParams type.

Comment: @SergeyTerentyev what’s the problem?

Comment: Also I tried to modify signature of method by adding MessageProvider to a parameter list but unfortunately system wasn't capable to resolve mine QueryStringBinder anymore:
implicit def queryStringBinder(implicit intBinder: QueryStringBindable[Int], messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)